# Suitable Condition to echo the result

Tags: php

I have written a case as shown below,

```
case 'yesno':
{
    if ($reg['answer'])
    {
        $reg['answer'] = $phrase['_yes'];

    }
    else
    {
        $reg['answer'] = $phrase['_no'];
    }
//below line is to be corrected 
($reg['answer'] =$phrase['_yes'])? $show['answer_icon'] = true : $show['answer_icon'] = false;
        echo $show['answer_icon'];
    break;
 }
```

I need to show an image as result only if

```
     $reg['answer'] = $phrase['_yes'];
```

But right now the condition which I have written for that is showing error(above comemnted line)

It shows all result with an image,irrestpective of yes or no when I write the below condition

```
    ($reg['answer'])? $show['answer_icon'] = true : $show['answer_icon'] = false;
```

Can any one suggest the right condition for this... Showing an image part has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close buddy. Try this:

```
 $show['answer_icon'] = ($reg['answer'] == $phrase['_yes']) ? true : false;
```

Comment: again the result is same i have echo the result and it shows 111111111

Comment: That's because true/false is evaluated to 1 or 0.

Use this then:
`$show['answer_icon'] = ($reg['answer'] == $phrase['_yes']) ? "true" : "false";`

The quotes will turn true and false into strings :o)

Comment: the `? true : false` part is redundant, as it is exactly what the previous part also evaluates to.

Comment: IN the first example yes. However he needs true and false as a string. So its not redundant.

Comment: Your code sets the variable as the boolean version of true and false, not the string.

Comment: Read the second comment to this to my answer:

"That's because true/false is evaluated to 1 or 0. Use this then: $show['answer_icon'] = ($reg['answer'] == $phrase['_yes']) ? "true" : "false"; The quotes will turn true and false into strings :o)"

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single equal `=` to compare, and it should be double `==`. But you  can also shorten your string a lot like this:

```
$show['answer_icon'] = ($reg['answer'] == $phrase['_yes']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a single equals, which will always return true as it assigning the value of $phrase['_yes'] to  $reg['answer'] which returns true (ie. the value has been assigned).

Firstly you need to be doing == for comparison.

Ie. 
    ($reg['answer'] == $phrase['_yes'])?

Answer (score 0):

you need '==' operator to compare it try the below line

```
$show['answer'] = ($reg['answer'] == $phrase['_yes']) ? true :  false;
                        echo $show['answer'];
```